# How to Retrieve the columns of particularlist view from any standard object or custom object in salesforce

Tags: apex

I got a requirement that to do mass edit on particular object that edit operation can perform on only fields which are visible from the list view. **How can I Retrieve the columns of a particular list view from any standard object or custom object in salesforce ?**

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to access the metadata API to get at this information, which isn't supported for Apex by Salesforce.  Financial Force have a project in github that provides access to this API via Apex, so you may be able to use that (I haven't tried this so I can't say for sure that it will allow you to do what you need):

https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Comment: Yes indeed this is the way to go, once Spring'14 is rolled out retrieve will become much easier, currently you need to manage this via an async and unzip component, as per the demo included in the library. Once Salesforce release Spring'14 i have a release planned.  More details on new MD API features here http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/12/24/updating-layouts-in-apex/